# .children .val() is throwing undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to form validation but .val() seems to be giving undefined.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $('.formElem .input').each(function() {    
    $(this).children(".inputField").on("keyup", function() {

      console.log($(this).children('#username').val());

    });
  });
});
```

This is the html part

```
<form action="#" class="formElem" method="post" autocomplete="off">
 <div class="input username_container">
        <input class="inputField" id="username" maxlength="50" placeholder="Username" name="username" size="20" tabindex="1" type="text">               
        <div class="tip">
          <p class="blank error">Field cannot be empty</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: And what HTML are you working with? Can you reproduce a ([minimal/sscce](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to play/work with?

Comment: The selector is probably wrong since it's unlikely you have a `<username>` tag.

Comment: what is username, is that a class, an id? Should you have # or . there?

Comment: I just edited the post with the html. thank you guys

Comment: `#username` is not a direct children of `$(this)` -- in fact it is the same element. But since it's an id, there's no reason not to use just `$( '#username' )`.

Comment: @Juhana i cant directly use it since im looping through many and all are different

Comment: Does that mean you have multiple elements with the same id? It's not allowed. All ids must be unique.

Comment: @Juhana no all have different ID but the idea is to toop and get value of that one in the loop instead of writing code for all element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a dumb ass question. Only posted due to fact that i didn't know how to search it. But thanks to @Juhana for the answer

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 3):

`'username'` is not a valid parameter to pass to `.children()`

`input` would work if you're targeting an input field, as would `.username` if you have a class specified on the child.

Comment: It is a valid parameter if there exists such a tag.

Comment: You are correct; but since there does not exist a `<username>` tag anywhere in the HTML spec (nor any plans for one)...

Comment: Which HTML spec do you mean? It is possible in XHTML. And it will work with HTML even if it's not standard. (But yes, it is highly unlikely that the OP has `<username>` anywhere.)

Comment: @Juhana, XHTML does not have a `<username>` element, not does HTML5... see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-xhtml2-20050527/elements.html & here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html